# IntelliJ IDEA/ Grails not resolving plugins

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-plugin

I have been using IntelliJ for almost a year ad I have always been really happy with it. However, yesterday I set it up on my new laptop (Ubuntu 11.04), and haven't seen the plugins module since.. :-(

Ran `grails clean`, tried to change the project structure/settings to include `$HOME/.grails/1.3.x/projects/projectName/plugins`, but still nothing. My understanding is that it should pick up the plugins automatically, am I right?

For the record, I am using Grails 1.3.4, IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 9.0.4.

Comment: You are sure that is a problem of IntelliJ? Have you tried 'grails list-plugins' in the shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend switching to the latest Intellij version (10.5.1 as of now). Support for Grails has been improved a lot since 9.x. If you don't want to upgrade, check the following areas:

- are all used classpath variables set correctly?
- are you referencing the correct Grails version?

Comment: I tried the latest release, 10.5.1 and indeed it resolved the plugin right away, but as always it is a matter of cost :-( the weird thing is that I never had this kind of issue with the previous release, 9.0.4. Weird stuff, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Upgrading Intellij is definitly worth the costs, increased productivity pays off soon.

Comment: Indeed, 10.5.1 did the trick, it is working like a charm now!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using IntelliJ 11.1.3 with Grails 2.1.1.

General Issue:
The IDE Build/Make Project/Run Unit-tests sometimes fails to resolve classes referenced as dependencies within Plugins and produces 'no class...' errors.  Normal grails targets (compile, run-app, test-app) work without issue!

Workaround:
Restarting IntelliJ 'magically' corrected my Plugin related 'no class...' errors.

What didn't work:
grails resolve-dependencies (makes sense because grails run-app worked fine!)
grails clean (again makes sense this is just purging the output)

Seems like the IDE Build/Make Project/Run Unit-tests uses a stale classpath in some circumstances.  Unfortunately I don't have a repeatable test case but noticed that modifying BuildConfig and doing grails refresh-dependencies or compile or run-app doesn't make the IDE update it's list of grailsPlugins!

Answer (score 2):

I've had IDEA do this once in a while to me as well. Even in the latest version (though I do agree you should upgrade, but 9->10 isn't free).  For me, I just had to kill IDEA and restarted it.

Comment: It seems that I am not the only one and the issue keeps coming randomly for most of the users. Restarting/re-installing seems to solve the issue, well, not for me! Thanks anyways Gregg!

Answer (score 2):

IMPORTANT UPDATE! It will be fixed in 11.1.2! YEEAAAH!

In my case plugins not resolving because of custom system property 'grails.work.dir'. If your project using default 'grails.work.dir' than OK otherwise plugins won't be resolved. Tested on Idea 10.5.4, 11.1.1 and windows 7.